# How to create copy of full schema on same database in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

Currently Redshift do not provide privilege to create copy of full schema on same database in Redshift. I followed this(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_SCHEMA.html), but did not get any information on my question

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use below query to copy your data from one schema to another.

Create table new_schema.table_name as select * from old_schema.table_name.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I used some dynamic SQL to copy a schema in a more automated way. Posting it here in case it's useful for anyone.

Caveat: This works only if constraints in primary and foreign keys are not relevant.

1. Create the new schema:

   ```
    CREATE SCHEMA new_schema_name
   ```
2. Create the following stored procedure:

   ```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE support.sp_migrate_schema(original_schema VARCHAR(512), new_schema VARCHAR(512)) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
    -- CALL support.sp_migrate_schema('original_schema_name','new_schema_name')
    DECLARE
        rec     RECORD;
        teststr VARCHAR(65535) = '';    
    BEGIN 
        FOR rec IN  
            SELECT 
                t.table_name
            FROM information_schema.tables t
            WHERE 
                t.table_schema = original_schema 
                AND t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND t.table_name NOT IN
                (
                    SELECT 
                        table_name
                    FROM information_schema.tables
                    WHERE 
                        table_schema = new_schema 
                        AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                )
        LOOP 
            EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + new_schema + '.' + rec.table_name + ' (LIKE ' + original_schema + '.' + rec.table_name + ');';
            teststr := 'INSERT INTO ' + new_schema + '.' + rec.table_name + '('; 
            teststr := teststr + 'SELECT * ';
            teststr := teststr + 'FROM ' + original_schema + '.' + rec.table_name + ');';
            EXECUTE teststr;
        END LOOP;
    END;
    $$;
   ```

This procedure will create an empty table in the new schema for each table in the old schema that does not exist yet in the new schema. If the new schema is empty, the last condition in the `WHERE` statement can be omitted. These tables will have the same structure and properties as the original ones, except for constraints in primary and foreign keys (as per Redshift documentation on `CREATE TABLE new_table (LIKE original_table)`). Subsequently, the procedure is going to insert all data from the tables present in the original schema into the newly created copies in the new schema.

3. Run the procedure:

   ```
    CALL support.sp_migrate_schema('original_schema_name','new_schema_name')
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a copy of all the tables **with data**. If so then you will have to:

1. Create the new schema
2. Retrieve the DDL for all tables in existing schema

   - Use this view: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql
3. Modify the DDL to reference the new schema
4. Run the DDL to create the target tables
5. Run an `INSERT INTO new_schema.new_table SELECT * FROM old_schema.old_table;` for each table in the schema.

Comment: Can you suggest a quicker way or command with less human intervention ?

Comment: It's sad that this is still a hard operation